# Selecting a Deeply Nested Checkbox Needs to Select Parent Checkboxes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I'm trying to select a deeply nested checkbox child, and when doing so, my jQuery code will also select the parent checkboxes above it in the DOM. I then want to store the IDs of the parent checkboxes by using the IDs of the deeply nested child checkboxes.

My sample code doesn't work properly as constructed.

Sample: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uR2B/).

**Code:**

```html
<form action="" method="POST" id="RoleForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Role Name</label><input id="rolename" required="" class="form-control" name="rolename" placeholder="Add Role Name" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Role Description</label>
    <textarea id="roledesc" required="" class="form-control" name="roledesc" placeholder="Add Role Description"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <ul>
      <li style="display: block; width: 100%;float: left;">
        <input name="page" value="page-1" type="checkbox">Cockpit <br>
        <ul>
          <li style="display: block;width: 20%;float:left;">
            <input name="action" value="action-1" type="checkbox">Update Deposit Amount <br>
          </li>
          <li style="display: block;width: 20%;float:left;">
            <input name="action" value="action-2" type="checkbox">Pay To Captain <br>
          </li>
          <li style="display: block;width: 20%;float:left;">
            <input name="action" value="action-3" type="checkbox">My Action <br>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li style="display: block; width: 100%;float: left;">
        <input name="page" value="page-2" type="checkbox">Dashboard <br>
        <ul>
          <li style="display: block;width: 20%;float:left;">
            <input name="action" value="action-2" type="checkbox">Update Deposit Amount <br>
          </li>
          <li style="display: block;width: 20%;float:left;">
            <input name="action" value="action-1" type="checkbox">Pay To Captain <br>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li style="display: block; width: 100%;float: left;">
        <input name="page" value="page-5" type="checkbox">TestPage <br>
        <ul>
          <li style="display: block;width: 20%;float:left;">
            <input name="action" value="action-2" type="checkbox">Pay To Captain <br>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```js
var pageArray = [];
var actionArray = [];
$('input[name="page"]:checked').each(function() {
  pageArray.push($(this).val());
  $('input[name="action"]:checked').each(function() {
    actionArray.push($(this).val());
  });
});
alert(actionArray);
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: provide some more details.

Comment: I have a form with parent child checkboxes like this url.
http://jsfiddle.net/7uR2B/
i want to store parent with its child in database. @B001ᛦ

Comment: @PranbirSarkar please check

Comment: _i want to store parent..._  Again, post the code which is trying to save data to db

Comment: var pageArray = [];
                var actionArray = [];
                $('input[name="page"]:checked').each(function() {
                     pageArray.push($(this).val());
                      $('input[name="action"]:checked').each(function() {
                         actionArray.push($(this).val());
                         });
                });

                alert(actionArray);

Comment: A screenshot and samples of code will help. Also ,don't post code into comments and update your post with it.

Comment: dude.. where is your php code? where is your mysql query?

Comment: Guys before storing it into database i want the data. i want to get selected parent child values. that's it. the storing into db has no problem. but before that i want to access checked values.

Comment: @DanishJamshed ... You can do one thing... when you want to store the data just fetch all the selected checkbox and then you can send the fetched data via ajax and store in Database.. Is it what you want ?

Comment: yes but i don't know how to fetch each parent's child. so i can send data to ajax like parent1 has child 1,2,3 and parent 2 has child 2,3. i have updated code please have a look.

Comment: @PranbirSarkar have a look into my jquery code.

Comment: @Alex i have updated my question.

Comment: anything guys ?

Comment: Why not make the id's of the parents part of the value of the deeply nested child checkboxes (using seperators)? So the value of first checkbox "Update Deposit Amount" will become something like "page-1|action-1". Simple and you got all the information (id's, values, whatever) you need.